# searching CSV File with PHP

Tags: php, search, csv

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
603629,0,ATLV0008,"Vendor1",1942.60,11/04/2010,1942.60,9/1-9/30/10,EFT-JP
603627,2,ATLV0008,"Vendor1",1242.40,11/04/2010,1242.40,7/1-7/31/10,EFT-JP
600023,0,FLD4V0003,"Vendor2",1950.00,06/15/2010,1950.00,6/14/10 Request,EFT-JP
600024,0,FLD4V0003,"Vendor2",1800.00,06/15/2010,1800.00,6/14/10 Request,EFT-JP
603631,0,ATLV5066,"Vendor2",1000.00,11/09/2010,1000.00,11/4/10 Check Request,PM2
603647,0,ATLV5027,"DVendor3",2799.80,11/15/2010,2799.80,10/1-10/31/10 Bishop,PM2
603642,5,ATLV5027,"Vendor3",482.40,11/15/2010,482.40,10/1-10/18/10 Allen,PM2
603653,0,ATLV0403,"Vendor4",931.21,11/17/2010,931.21,9/1-9/30/10,EFT-JP
603661,0,ATLV0105,"Vendor5",26.75,11/19/2010,26.75,093139,PM2
603660,1,ATLV0105,"Vendor5",5.35,11/19/2010,5.35,093472,PM2
```

I'm using fgetcsv to import this file and then export it to xml and display it properly with html.

It needs to be organized according to Office (ATL in 2n field) and Vendor.  The file will not be sorted in any which way.  What's the best way to search through the file?

This is what I have so far:

```
if (($handle = fopen('upload/ATLANTA.csv', "r")) !== FALSE) { 
      while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ","))) {  
         $currOffice = substr($data[2], 0, 3);
                  foreach ($data as $key => $d) {
                    if ($key != 1){
                    $invoiceData = "<div class=\"field\">" .$d . "</div>";
                    }
                    $prevVendor = $data[3];
                    $prevOffice = $currOffice;
                } 
      }
  }
```

Comment: Actually, when I'm querying the data I could order it by the 3rd and fourth column.

Comment: If it's a quick one-time search, RegEx on the raw data may perform better than storing the data in arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First (and this is just me) I would clean the data up by creating a multi-dimensional array like so...

```
if (file_exists('ATLANTA.csv') != FALSE) {
    $handle  = file_get_contents('ATLANTA.csv') or exit;
    $handle_row = explode("\n", $handle);
    foreach ($handle_row as $key => $val) {
        $row_array = explode(',', $val);
        foreach ($row_array as $key => $val) {
            $row_array[$key] = trim(str_replace('"', '', $val));
            }
        $complete[] = $row_array;
        }
    }
```

Then, pass $complete through the following function to sort by your second tier arrays' values.

```
$array_elem_01 = 2; // Which Column to Sort By
$array_elem_02 = 3; // <-- Edit
if (isset($complete)) {
    foreach ($complete as $key => $val) {
        $sort_01[$key] = $val[$array_elem_01] . $val[$array_elem_02]; // <-- Edit
        }
    asort($sort_01);
    foreach ($sort_01 as $key => $val) {
        $output[] = $complete[$key];
        }
    }
return $output;
```

Comment: One of the values has a comma in it and it separates it into 2 separate entries within the array, how do I stop this from happening?

Comment: Is it possible to now sort again according to the 3rd element similar to what can be done in sql - ORDER BY 2, 3.

Comment: Note my above edits to cascade your sort order. Which value in you csv is separated by a comma?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [PHP manual page for the array_search() function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php).

It doesn't do exactly what you need, but the most recent user comment on the page provides a function that searches a multi-level array, that looks to me like it would be a perfect match for your requirements.

Hope that helps.